# Custom Data Access Layer Transaction Management

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton, data-access-layer

I have a data access layer (`DatabaseHelper`) and I am using it mostly in web applications. Inside my `DatabaseHelper` class, there are `DbConnection`, `DbProviderFactory` and `DbTransaction` fields. For example my `ExecuteNonQuery` method like this:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string cmd, CommandType commandType, DbParameter[] parameters = null)
{
    int num;
    this.OpenDbConnection();
    try
    {
        DbCommand command = this.connection.CreateCommand();
        //command.transaction = this.transaction; // I am not sure of this line
        command.CommandText = cmd;
        command.CommandType = commandType;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        }
        num = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        num = -1;
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.CloseDbConnection();
    }
    return num;
}
```

I am using this class with singleton pattern in my web application. As you know web applications are multithread by nature. My question is how can I handle transactions in my data access layer? Inside my application there is only one `DatabaseHelper` instance because of singleton pattern. Therefore, is it possible to overlap different thread's transactions? What is the correct usage of begin, commit and rollback transaction in this scenario?

Comment: you can use TransactionScope. it will work, but its not ideal. refactor your repositories so that they dont open and close the connection on each query

Comment: Why not use `ThreadLocal<T>` so you don't need to handle thread synchronization

Comment: When and how to open and close connections ideally?